# How can I use Mocha without removing Ava?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, ava

One of my co-workers added this `Ava` package to our setup, and it's done something I've never seen a Node package do before: interfere with other packages!  Now when I try to run Mocha I get:

```
$ node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha test/
Test files must be run with the AVA CLI:

    $ ava node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha
```

I get that Ava would like to run my Mocha tests, but if I wanted that I'd run `ava mocha` not `mocha`.  And because a co-worker is using it I can't simply uninstall the package.

Is there any way I can run plain Mocha tests on a machine with Ava installed?

Comment: Do your test files import from ava?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm writing a completely new Mocha test file, totally separate from Ava (with no Ava imports in it).

Comment: Right, but you're pointing at `test/` not a specific file. Sounds like something in that directory pulls in ava.

Comment: Judging by [ava's tests](https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/7bf78193dce2145157f3aa29f71650922fe9f24a/test/cli.js#L337-L343) that's the message you should see if ava is required without the cli.

Comment: Ah ha!  That appears to be the issue: another unrelated and non-Mocha file was in the `test` directory.  I thought it was strange that one package would interfere with another!  If you'd like to put your comments in the form of an answer (something to the effect "what you're seeing can only happen if Ava is being imported somehow, so you must be importing it from somewhere") I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the files in `test/` imports `ava` and the imported code will recognise that it's not being run with the correct tooling and throw an error.

Might be worth subdividing your `test/` directory to keep tests associated with their respective runners.

```
test/
  ava/
    SomeAvaTests.js
  mocha/
    SomeMochaTests.js
```

This way you can safely run `mocha test/mocha/` and vice versa without worrying about treading on each other's toes.